# How to troubleshoot a previous Exchange 2010 error with emails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, exchange-2010

A client of ours reported that from Tuesday evening to this morning, no emails were being received, then all of a sudden everyone's emails came through all at once. This is internal as well as external mail

I am in the Exchange Management Console, and I know there are many logs and troubleshooters, but I have no idea the correct way to determine what happened.

Email seems to be flowing as it should now, but this same issue has happened a couple of times this year.

Any help would be fantastic!

Thanks.

Update: Issue has happened again with the same client, this time lasting about an hour, then all emails came through at once.

Update again: The client failed to tell us that this was only happening on mobile devices and not outlook. Then it turned out it was just two people with bad reception

Comment: Anyway to put this as a bounty question early? Not something that can wait two days.

Comment: Sounds like back pressure. How much free space (as a percentage) is available on the drives that hold the mailbox database(s) and transaction logs?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The client failed to tell us that this was only happening on mobile devices and not outlook. Then it turned out it was just two people with bad reception. grr!